# How to get path to *.sln file from within xUnit test

Tags: xunit

In our solution we host a folder containing a 3rd party program.
Using xUnit I am working on a unit test that ensures the correct funktionality of some of those 3rd party components.

How can I get hold of the path to the 3rd party components, relativly to the solution directory?